# Trying to install gd, getting conflict error

Tags: linux, centos, php, gd

I am trying to install gd using `sudo yum install php-gd` but I get the error below. I know I have ran into this problem before but I can't seem to recall how I got around it. Am I in the wrong directory? Did I update PHP incorrectly at some point? My brain seems to have turned off for the night and I can't figure this one out.

> --> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.8-1.w6.i386 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
>
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686`

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the _other_ packages that start with `php55w-` and why didn't you prefix this one the same way?

Comment: Mostly because I have no idea what I am doing, unfortunately this was months ago and I don't recall where I got them.

Comment: Ah okay, pretty easy fix. `yum install php55w-gd` then restarted apache.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need check PHP version you have installed

> # php -v

After this you need to find php-gd package for your version of PHP, cause yo are trying php-gd for PHP 5.5.*, but you (probably) have PHP 5.3.*.
So you can try:

1. I assume you have REMI or CentALT repo installed, so just try installing pgp-gd from those repos.

   > # yum install php-gd
2. If you need newer version of PHP ==>> PHP GD:

   1. Remove Current PHP, the easy way is:

      > # rpm -qa | grep php | xargs yum -y remove
   2. Install PHP version you need:

      > > # yum install php55w-common php55w-gd  ...